# Does ria services have something like sqlclient SqlCommand for executing T-SQL?

Tags: wcf-ria-services, ria

How would ria services do this kind of thing?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string TSQL="update products set price=price*1.03 where category='computer books'";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(TSQL, connection);
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need get all entites of Product with category *computer books* and then update price for them and save changes to DB.

Comment: Hi Serhii,

So...
I have to pull all the "computer books" onto the client, then update the price, then submit the changes?
I was hoping for the ability to directly execute a tsql "update" (not having to pull the data to the client just to update it).
Anything like that in ria?

Comment: >Anything like that in ria?

No, for current version of WCF RIA Services.